# Menu shifting upon re-size

Tags: html, css

When you open the browser at full size, the menu is centered (That's where it's supposed to be) however, if you open the browser while the browser is not at full size (restore down) , the menu isn't centered under the .logo (as seen in the jsfiddle), but at the ultimate right. Any help?

PS: the menu has an animation feature upon clicking one of its elements.

Code of the menu:

```
<div id="logo" class="logo" ><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></div>
        <p class="custom-class"><a href="">Go to the main website</a></p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"><button>A</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button>B</button></li>
            <li id="item3"><button>C       </button></li>
            <li id="item4"><button>D        </button></li>
            <li id="item5"><button>E   </button></li>
            <li id="item6"><button>F      </button></li>
            <li id="item7"><button>G      </button></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
       $(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});


        var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}

.custom-class {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:-130px;
    margin-right: 20px;

}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

samp {
    display: none;
}

img {
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
.logo {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top:40px;

}

 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align:right;    
    border-style: none;

}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;

   }

.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 695px;
  right:0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;

}

#item7{
  transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
}
#item6{
  transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
}
#item5{
  transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
}
#item4{
  transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
}
#item3{
  transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
}
#item2{
  transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
}
#item1{
  transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
}


#item1>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item3>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item4>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item5>button{vertical-align:top; height:25px;width:200px; background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item6>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item7>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}

.permahover li{
opacity: 1;
left: 10%;

}

.headlines li{
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.headlines:hover li,
.headlines.active li{            /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;  
    cursor: pointer;                    /* Dim all */
}    
.headlines li:hover,
.headlines li.active {      /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;                /* Max one */
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer; 
}





@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/n4gwk6qs/

Comment: What is your reason for the following CSS? `.menu li{ left: 695px; right:0; }` I believe that is causing the behavior you mention. Also, you may want to move relevant CSS from the JSFiddle into your question.

Comment: @mfcovington if i removed the .menu li{ left: 695px; right:0; } the menu won't be in the center under the image

Comment: Maybe the JSFiddle is acting differently, because with that code, the letters are far right. Without the code, they are aligned to left edge of image. Where exactly do you want them?

Comment: @mfcovington the js is acting the same as the browser. I want them in the middle of the website, under the right end of the image. And upon clicking on one of the elements the animation starts. It's working as how i want when the browser is full-size. But i resize the window, the result is as in the jsfiddle

Comment: I see. Well, I still believe `.menu li{ left: 695px; }` is part your problem. It is forcing your menu to be 695px from the left, so when your screen gets smaller, it gets pushed too far the the right.

Comment: @mfcovington true, i believe the problem is between .menu and .menu li the position of .menu seems to determine whether the animation works or not. And what's in my jsfiddle is the only way that i could implement to make the animation work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take my advice, **always**, include a CSS Reset for your website. This sets all the properties of all elements to their default value. You can find one [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

To center the menu, I used `margin: auto;` together with `top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;`

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/n4gwk6qs/3/

Also, please organize your code. You declare the same properties for the same elements multiple times. Doesn't hurt but doesn't look very pretty.

Comment: that's what i want, but the animation isn't working anymore

Comment: What do you want the animation to do?

Comment: upon clicking on an element in the menu, the menu shift to the ultimate left of the website, in this form /    as in the jsfiddle in my post

Comment: Sure, gimme a second.

Comment: are you still working on it? because you're my only hope :)

Comment: Yes, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gwk6qs/2/) does it, but when you zoom out it still doesn't display correctly. Still working on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81137/discussion-between-randy-and-theonlyerror).

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Comment: I aint just still at school for another two hours